# How to prove an email left our system with tracing?

Tags: .net, trace, smtpclient

We have a system that sends out emails from an email queue table in Sql Server. It reads a set of unsent records from the queue, sends them, and then updates them all with a sent date.

We have some users who are complaining that they are not getting the emails (though most users are getting them just fine). The records have sent dates set on them though, indicating that the process sent all the emails successfully, before marking them sent. If it had encountered any errors, then the records would have not had sent dates filled in, as that is the last thing that is done in the process.

However, this keeps being sent back to me, that "the program's not working!" So I want to be able to prove that specific emails went out. I turned on `System.Net` and `System.Net.Sockets` tracing for the .NET framework. I sent out a test email via the system, and I see it logged in the trace file. However I don't see anything on the trace that actually shows WHAT email it was for, nothing about the recipient address, or the body or anything, that I can see.

I was hoping for something like an SMTP log, showing `Message X to recipient Y was successfully handed off to, and accepted by the server on such-and-such date/time.` so as to prove **Yes, your email successfully left our server; if you are not receiving it, the problem is somewhere down stream from us.** But I don't see that information in the trace log.

Are there any switches I can turn on for the tracing that would give this level of info? Or some other way I can go about this?

The messages are being sent through the client's Office 365 account, using the .NET SmtpClient class.

Here are the current trace settings I have...

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
        <source name="System.Net" >
            <listeners>
                <add name="MyTraceFile"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
            <listeners>
                <add name="MyTraceFile"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add 
            name="MyTraceFile"
            type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData="F:\Trace\System.Net.trace.log" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
        <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
        <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Aside from the other actions others might suggest, my 5 cents would be to check if you have bursts in the way you send those mails. Maybe some points in time where there is a larger than usual batch of emails pending to be transmitted. If that were the case, there might be a set of other possible root causes for your problem to look into.

Answer (score 0):

If an email is delivered and no-one is around to hear it, did it still make a sound? ;)

There are a few trace options that it looks like you've explored. But a low-tech option is to include a second recipient or a BCC address to a mailbox that you control, then you 'have the email right here'. Bonus points if that mailbox is off-domain.